# error with mariadb 10.0.8 and mysqli extension

Tags: php, mariadb

Hi i just installed mariadb to replace mysql in my WHM/cpanel server but when im running a website using mysqli extesion i get error connecting to the db then i debug the output when compiling the php i saw this:

```
MySQL version '10.0.8' is neither 4 nor 5, skipping mysqli
```

what should i do to install mysqli with the latest version of mariadb? i used this method to build all extensions and modules:

```
/scripts/easyapache --build
```

but didnt work, i cant install the mysqli extension.

thank you very much.

Comment: See [this page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installation-issues-with-php5/). It is for differing minor versions, but I would assume that your error would be similar.

Comment: well that gave me a light i just recompile the php manually and worked perfect now i can use mysqli, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i just configured and compiled php manually using:

```
cd /home/cpeasyapache/src/
```

then

```
php -i|grep configure
```

and

run this command

> Configure Command => './configure' '--enable-bcmath'
>   '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp'
>   '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes'
>   '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets'
>   '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local'
>   '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-bz2'
>   '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers'
>   '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd'
>   '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr'
>   '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64'
>   '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/'
>   '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr'
>   '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
>   '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr'
>   '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre'
>   '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic'
>   '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-sqlite=shared' '--with-xmlrpc'
>   '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'